# AWS sign-in InvalidParameterException Missing required parameter SRP_A

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-cpp

I want to apply that statement for cpp:

I tried to adopt it cpp. I could sign-up operation. When I tried to sign-in, I encountered that exception:
"InvalidParameterException : Missing required parameter SRP_A"

This is part of my code:

```
    Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::String> authParameters;

   Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::String> authParameters;
    authParameters.insert(
        std::pair<Aws::String, Aws::String>("USERNAME", "xxxxx"));
    authParameters.insert(
        std::pair<Aws::String, Aws::String>("PASSWORD", "xxxxx"));

    InitiateAuthRequest initiateAuthRequest;
    initiateAuthRequest.SetAuthFlow(
        Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Model::AuthFlowType::USER_SRP_AUTH);
    initiateAuthRequest.SetClientId(TEST_APP_CLIENT_ID);
    initiateAuthRequest.SetAuthParameters(authParameters);

    InitiateAuthOutcome initiateAuthOutcome =
        client.InitiateAuth(initiateAuthRequest);
    if (initiateAuthOutcome.IsSuccess()) {
        qDebug() << "Initiate auth: " << initiateAuthOutcome.IsSuccess();
    } else {
        qDebug() << initiateAuthOutcome.GetError().GetExceptionName().c_str()
                 << ": " << initiateAuthOutcome.GetError().GetMessage().c_str();
    }
```

How can I add SRP_A attribute to InitiateAuthRequest? For other platforms (android, ios and js), their sdk has SRP_A generator like there.

How can I solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In many of the lower level SDKs you need to implement the SRP auth yourself, if you are on an untrusted device, i.e. you cannot store full IAM credentials on it, and therefore cannot use the Admin* functions.

I [wrote a blogpost about adding SRP in the AWS C# SDK](http://blog.mmlac.com/aws-cognito-srp-login-c-sharp-dot-net/) which should give you a good starting point on what the process involves and what steps you need to take to do the math. It should be not too hard to port over to C++, you just need hashing libraries, like openssl/hmac.

Your first issue here is that you need to send a SRP_A value, but that alone won't solve your issue, as you will just get a SRP challenge returned, so I am refering you to my post that goes through the whole SRP process.

If you are in a trusted environment though, i.e. you are running your C++ code on your own server that *only you* have access to, none of your customers, and you don't ship your c++ code to anyone, then you can use the [AdminInitiateAuth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html) methods with the ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH authentication method (that you have to enable when you create a new client id / secret id for your pool, which allows you to just send username and password in plain text.